# Assign default value by object destructuring to object's properties

Tags: javascript

Is it somehow possible to destructure an object, set a default value, and assign this default value directly to the object's property?

Consider this code

```js
let foo = {};
let {bar = 1} = foo;
console.log(foo); // {}
console.log(bar); // 1
```

As you can see, `foo` still doesn't have a `bar` property. Is there something like below possible, to assign the prop and default value directly to the object:

```
let {bar = 1: foo.bar}
```

This is obvious illegal syntax.

Is there any one liner I can use to get `foo` to be

```
{bar: 1}
```

after the destructuring is done?

Comment: what do you mean by destructuring? Are you talking about inheritance here in some way?

Comment: @RehanUmar I mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: You can use spread syntax to add new object props to existing one , or you want to use destructuring in this case ?

Comment: Maybe inline if bar ? bar : 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take the object with property as target by using the [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern).

```js
var foo = {};

({ bar: foo.bar = 1 } = foo);
console.log(foo);

foo.bar = 42;
({ bar: foo.bar = 1 } = foo);
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: Thanks. From what I've read this is the closest it will get. Do you see any chance to also define `bar` like it would have been in the question?

Comment: do you mean to get a variable `bar` **and** an assignment to the property at the same time? if so, i see no choice, because with only `bar`, you get a new variable, and with `bar: foo.bar`, it's part of the destructuring chain.

Comment: Yes exactly. I don't think it's possible either atm.